# Python: Python.h file missing

Tags: python, gcc, anaconda, murmurhash

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to install Murmurhash python library but it is throwing error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1 . I looked on Internet and it is says that this error is due to missing python header files. So i did

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

but still the error is there. Is the error because i have Anaconda installed or what ? Can somebody help me as in how to rectify this error. Error is as follow :

```
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'mmh3' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c mmh3module.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/mmh3module.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:81:0,
             from mmh3module.cpp:3:
mmh3module.cpp: In function ‘int mmh3_traverse(PyObject*, visitproc, void*)’:
mmh3module.cpp:107:63: error: ‘PyModule_GetState’ was not declared in this scope
 #define GETSTATE(m) ((struct module_state*)PyModule_GetState(m))
                                                           ^
/usr/include/python2.7/objimpl.h:326:13: note: in definition of macro ‘Py_VISIT’
     if (op) {                                                       \
         ^
mmh3module.cpp:134:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘GETSTATE’
 Py_VISIT(GETSTATE(m)->error);
          ^
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:80:0,
             from mmh3module.cpp:3:
mmh3module.cpp: In function ‘int mmh3_clear(PyObject*)’:
mmh3module.cpp:107:63: error: ‘PyModule_GetState’ was not declared in this scope
#define GETSTATE(m) ((struct module_state*)PyModule_GetState(m))
                                                           ^
/usr/include/python2.7/object.h:816:13: note: in definition of macro ‘Py_CLEAR’
if (op) {                               \
         ^

mmh3module.cpp:139:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘GETSTATE’
 Py_CLEAR(GETSTATE(m)->error);
          ^
mmh3module.cpp: At global scope:
mmh3module.cpp:143:27: error: variable ‘PyModuleDef mmh3module’ has initializer but incomplete type
 static struct PyModuleDef mmh3module = {
                       ^
 mmh3module.cpp:144:5: error: ‘PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT’ was not declared in this scope
 PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
 ^
 mmh3module.cpp: In function ‘void PyInit_mmh3()’:
mmh3module.cpp:157:51: error: ‘PyModule_Create’ was not declared in this scope
 PyObject *module = PyModule_Create(&mmh3module);
                                               ^
In file included from /usr/include/wchar.h:51:0,
             from /usr/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:120,
             from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:85,
             from mmh3module.cpp:3:
mmh3module.cpp:160:16: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
     return NULL;
            ^
mmh3module.cpp:107:63: error: ‘PyModule_GetState’ was not declared in this scope
#define GETSTATE(m) ((struct module_state*)PyModule_GetState(m))
                                                           ^
mmh3module.cpp:164:31: note: in expansion of macro ‘GETSTATE’
 struct module_state *st = GETSTATE(module);
                           ^
mmh3module.cpp:166:60: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
 st->error = PyErr_NewException("mmh3.Error", NULL, NULL);
                                                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/wchar.h:51:0,
             from /usr/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:120,
             from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:85,
             from mmh3module.cpp:3:
mmh3module.cpp:169:16: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
     return NULL;
            ^
mmh3module.cpp:172:12: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
 return module;
        ^
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: The C++ part of the Python package seems to be faulty and as a result it does not compile.

Comment: @KlausD. But the same is running in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: The GCC got more strict over the years. You might be able to compile manually by setting the right flags to suppress the error. You can see them in `[ ]` at the end of the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried a docker container with `ubuntu 16.04`

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y python-pip
pip install mmh3
```

That seems to be working. In your machine, you can just try.

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-pip
sudo pip install mmh3
```

With this you will be sure whether it is or not an anaconda problem with `gcc`.

I also checked anaconda with ubuntu 14.04 with the command `pip install mmh3`. It appears to be working too.