# I tried to install emcee and corner for python (linux). I got missing 'python.h' during installation. How to fix the corner installation?

Tags: python, module, installation, dependencies, apt-get

I tried to install 'emcee' for python. It seems to work. To start I tried the example here
http://dfm.io/emcee/current/user/line/

I want to get such corner plots as in the example so I've to install 'corner' too. 
This fails.

Uninstallation and reinstallation of wheel with pip get some small progress, but now I stuck.

I'm using the life Linux Knoppix8.1 and python2.7.

I tried

```
$ pip install corner
```

It seems to try to recompile matplotlib (and other) with gcc and the main error seems to be:

> fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

That means the Python.h file is missing.

I tried then the often suggested

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

But this fails too with:

> Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
>   Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig Paket python-dev ist
>   nicht verfügbar, wird aber von einem anderen Paket referenziert. Das
>   kann heißen, dass das Paket fehlt, dass es abgelöst wurde oder nur aus
>   einer anderen Quelle verfügbar ist. Doch die folgenden Pakete ersetzen
>   es:   python
>
> E: Für Paket »python-dev« existiert kein Installationskandidat.
>
> Thats German for python-dev is not available.

I tried also that suggested here, does not work too.
[Python: Python.h file missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068598/python-python-h-file-missing)

I seem to have generally problems with python modules with (graphical) output or the need of compilation with gcc. Pure calculation python modules seems to work mostly (at least for Python2.7).

How can I install corner to get the plots?
What should I try now?

Thank you for help.

UPDATE1:I made some progress.

My main focus is now to install 'python-dev'.

After updating

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

it knows now python-dev (great!) but there are dependencies.

After

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

It demands to install first: libpython-dev, python2.7-dev

After

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpython-dev
```

It demands to install first: libpython2.7-dev

After

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpython2.7-dev
```

It demands a different version of: libpython2.7-stdlib, libpython2.7

> Hängt ab von: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.13-2+deb9u3) aber 2.7.14~rc1-3 soll installiert werden
>
> Hängt ab von: libpython2.7 (= 2.7.13-2+deb9u3) aber 2.7.14~rc1-3 soll installiert werden

After

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpython2.7-stdlib
```

It demands a different version of: libssl1.1

> Hängt ab von: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) aber 1.1.0j-1~deb9u1 soll installiert werden

After

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl1.1
```

Installation works fine for the first time.

The problem I suck now is:

The version of 'libssl1.1' is now 1.1.0j-1~deb9u1 and it claims that this is the newest version. 
But 'libpython2.7-stdlib' demands the version >= 1.1.1

How can I solve this now?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Knoppix. But you might try installing python-devel. Different distributions name them somewhat differently.

Comment: That is similar to python-dev:E: Paket python-devel kann nicht gefunden werden.

Answer (score 0):

This is the duplicate question.

Please refer to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73251468/e-package-libssl1-1-has-no-installation-candidate) for installation of libssl