# python.h missing on Ubuntu 18 with python-dev installed

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, python-3.8

Trying to get fHDHR working Ubuntu 18. During the install I get this error:

```
include/python3.8 -c src/gevent/libev/corecext.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/gevent/libev/corecext.o
  src/gevent/libev/corecext.c:95:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   #include "Python.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for gevent
```

Most answers I find tell me I need python-dev installed but it already is (and updated).  In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068598/python-python-h-file-missing) post it was recommended to    `sudo pip install mmh3`   which I tried but it also failed as unable to find python.h

Any idea what I am missing on my system?

Answer (score 4):

You need to install python3.x-dev as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-with-exit). For me this resolved the issue.

Since from the error line we can see that you are running `python3.8`, so for your case you would need to do:

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install python3-dev.

```
apt install python3-dev
```

since you are using python3

Comment: python3-dev is installed

Answer (score 0):

When you are facing this error just do these install before installation package.

For **python 2.x** use:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

For **python 2.7** use:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

For **python 3.x** use:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

or for a specific version of Python 3, replace x with the minor version in

```
sudo apt-get install python3.x-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your current python version, i.e, *python --version*, perhaps you're on python 2.x, if True :

You have to switch on Python 3

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.x 2
```